# Problem writing changes back to access database from gridcontrol

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I am populating a gridcontrol (currently using DevExpress control but same issue if I use standard DataGridView) with data from an access database file (.accdb), and it works fine for showing my data.

But I can't seem to get it to save changes from the grid back to the database file, my adapter.update(table) command completes without error, but the changes are not written back to the file.

What am I missing?

```
Public Class Form1
  
    Dim connectionString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=.\test_databases\Database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"

    Dim connection As OleDbConnection
    Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dataSet As DataSet
    Dim commandBuilder As OleDbCommandBuilder
    Dim table As DataTable

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 
        ' Connect to Access Database
        connection = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        ' Query to select data from a table
        Dim query As String = "SELECT FileAs, Dateoflastvisit, Dateoflastservice ,EmailAddress  FROM Contacts_export_test"

        ' Create DataAdapter
        adapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, connection)

        ' Create command builder to generate update commands
        commandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)

        ' Create and fill table
        table = New DataTable
        adapter.Fill(table)

        ' Bind the Table to the GridControl
        GridControl1.DataSource = table

    End Sub
  

    Private Sub SimpleButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SimpleButton1.Click
       
        Try

            ' Ensure the connection is open
            If connection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then connection.Open()

            ' Update changes to the database
            adapter.Update(table)

            ' Close connection
            connection.Close()

            MessageBox.Show("Changes saved to the database successfully!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        Catch ex As Exception
         MessageBox.Show("Error saving changes: " & ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: When you call `Update` on your data adapter, there are three possible outcomes: it succeeds and returns a non-zero value, it succeeds and returns zero, or it fails and throws an exception. Which is it in your case? You say there's no error so it must be one of the other two. If it returns zero then there were no changes to save. If it returns a non-zero value then there were changes and they were saved.

Comment: Usually, the issue is that the developer doesn't know how local data files work and is looking in the wrong database for the changes. Have you added the database file to your project? If so, what is the value for its `Copy to Output Directory` property? It is probably `Copy Always`, which is the default. It should probably be `Copy if Newer`. Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsdata/2009/07/30/debugging-with-local-database-file/) for more information.

Comment: The value returned is non-zero and shows the number of changes made, BUT the underlying database is NOT being updated

Comment: Your second point got me thinking and like you said it was wrongly set to Copy Always!!, changes it to Copy if Newer and it now works.   Gutted I missed the obvious.  Thank you for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved thanks to suggestion from @jmcilhinney - the database I was testing with in my project was set to Copy Always rather than Copy if newer, so although my code was working it was overwriting the database the next time I ran the code.   Idiot.....